# Replace two values in a preg_replace pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a regex that searches for occurences like this in a text:

#### to find

`[pass id="HEH0Iu6rYl"][/pass]`

#### Regex

`preg_match_all('@\[pass id="(.*?)"\]\[\/pass\]@', $text, $matches);`

For all the found `$matches` I lookup the "code" in my Database and if found I want to fill the password from the database so that the text looks like this: `[pass id="HEH0Iu6rYl"]MYPASSWORD[/pass]`

#### Function

```
preg_match_all('@\[pass id="(.*?)"\]\[\/pass\]@', $docPart->getText(), $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $match) {

    /* Try to find existing Code and Update Password */
    $password = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Password')->findOneBy(array(
        'code' => $match,
    ));

    /* Check if it s Users own Password or User is able via AccesGroup */
    if($aG->getCanPassword() === true || $password->getUser() === $this->getUser()){
            
        /* Update the text */
        $pwText = preg_replace('#(\]).*?(\[/pass])#', $password->getPass(), $docPart->getText());
    }
}
```

But then the replacement looks like this: `[pass id="HEH0Iu6rYl"MYPASS`
How do I have to change the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this:

```
$pwText = preg_replace('#(\]).*?(\[/pass])#', '$1'.$password->getPass().'$2', $docPart->getText());
//                                            ^^^^^                    ^^^^^
```

`$1` contains the group 1 ie. `]` and `$2` contains `[/pass]`